# Conditionally add the ng-animate directive depending on a filter's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, phantomjs, ng-animate

I am developing a Single Page App using AngularJS.

Views are animated when *entering* and *leaving* using `ng-animate="{enter: 'appear', leave: 'disappear'}"`.

I wanted to make this SPA crawlable by search bots, so I am using a headless browser (PhantomJS) to render the page [while interpreting javascript], and then send that result back to the search bot.

The issue I am having is that PhantomJS sends back the result while the view is STILL animating, therefore some `div`s are still "transparent" when rendered back (or even sometimes still at `opacity:0` - Which is bad in terms of SEO imo).

My solution is to **disable animations when detecting a headless browser.**

My question is **how do i conditionally add the ng-animate directive depending on a filter's value ?**

I tried using directives:

```
<div id="content"
     data-ng-view
     ng-attr-ng-animate="{{ isHeadlessBrowser && '' }}"
     ng-animate="{enter: 'appear', leave: 'disappear'}"
     class="container"
></div>
```

But it doesn't work because the `ng-attr-ng-animate` renders to `nganimate` instead of `ng-animate`.. I also tried using `ng-attr-ng\-animate` and `ng-attr-ng--animate`.

I also tried using attr-class:

```
<div id="content"
     data-ng-view
     ng-attr-class="{{ isHeadlessBrowser && '.container' }}"
     class="container ng-animate:\"{enter: 'appear', leave: 'disappear'}\""
></div>
```

---

And for reference here is my headless browser detection filter:

```
(function (window, angular, $) {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('App.filters', [])
    .filter('isHeadlessBrowser',
      function(){
        return function(){
          return ( /(PhantomJS)/g.test(navigator.userAgent) );
        };
      }
    );

}(window, window.angular, window.jQuery));
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that as of Angular 1.2, the animations API has been refactored. You will no longer need the ng-animate attribute. http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Nice article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to bind `ng-animate` to a scope variable. Then set the object on the score from a controller `$scope.animations = isHeadlessBrowser ? { enter: ..., leave: ...} : {}`

In your directive use `ng-animate="animations"`

Answer (score 1):

You can globally disable animations during run() phase using [$animate.enabled(false)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate.%24animate#enabled)